# Global search in website using php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to implement search option in page header. Results will contain all records those contain filter text.e.g. products. ***What is the best way to implement global search in website***.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a global search in my site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798834/how-to-create-a-global-search-in-my-site)

Comment: Ok. i will check questions first here from onwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different approaches:

- Use `LIKE` queries in MySQL (very bad idea, no efficiency, no relevance)
- Use `full-text search` in MySQL (works from 3 characters, partly relevance)
- Use `Sphinx Search`, a full-text search with MySQL support
- Use a search engine, like `Elasticsearch` or `Solr`

I recommend you Sphinx Search. Very useful:

> Sphinx is a full-text search engine, publicly distributed under GPL version 2. Commercial licensing (eg. for embedded use) is available upon request.
>
> Technically, Sphinx is a standalone software package provides fast and relevant full-text search functionality to client applications. It was specially designed to integrate well with SQL databases storing the data, and to be easily accessed by scripting languages. However, Sphinx does not depend on nor require any specific database to function.
>
> Applications can access Sphinx search daemon (searchd) using any of the three different access methods: a) via Sphinx own implementation of MySQL network protocol (using a small SQL subset called SphinxQL, this is recommended way), b) via native search API (SphinxAPI) or c) via MySQL server with a pluggable storage engine (SphinxSE). (http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#about)

Comment: thanks @Schellingerht

Comment: Please mark the right answer, so other people can it use too. ;-)

Comment: yes. First let me check how to use Sphinx Search.

Comment: Sphinx Search is possible on shared hosting. That's a great advantage.